# Store value and use in again in the same controller Spring MVC

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, controller

I am trying to get url parameter and find a way to store them and use it in another method for a different .jsp but in the same controller. I was read that i can use modelattribute or sessionattribute but it doesn't seems to be working. Please do help me!

Url#1 : ..../Users/Id=3

Url#2 : ..../newUser

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/Id={id}" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listUser(ModelMap model, @PathVariable("id") Integer id) {        
        List<Usert> user = usere.findAllUsers(id); //retrieve the list from database 
        model.addAttribute("users", user);   
        model.addAttribute("userForm", id);
        return "management/userList";   
        }

/* Add New User */

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/newUser" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String newUser(ModelMap model) {

        NewForm newForm = new NewForm();
        model.addAttribute("NewForm", newForm);
        return "management/newUser";
    }

@RequestMapping(value = { "/newUser" },  method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String newUser(@Valid NewForm newForm,BindingResult result,  ModelMap model,
        HttpSession session,HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)throws IOException, ServletException, ParseException {

...

}
```

Comment: I did not get what do you want to do, but you can store it in a global variable

Comment: @DemonColdmist er i am trying to store the URL parameter that is taken out by pathvariable so that i can use it in another method within the same controller.

Comment: Just define a private variable in this controller, then you can store the information with this variable.

Comment: Thanks!! @DemonColdmist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Demon coldmist's method, i was able to solved this problem.

His answer:
*Define a private variable in this controller, then you can store the information with this variable.*